# Hugging Face : google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq - IndexError : index out of range in self

Tags: python

I using table parser model (google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq) from hugging face.
I am using it to ask questions on a excel file and get response.

I have all the required models.

Code

```
from transformers import AutoModelForTableQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer, pipeline
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel("excel path", sheet_name="Data")
table = table.astype(str)

model = 'google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq'
tapas_model = AutoModelForTableQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model)
tapas_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

# Initializing pipeline
nlp = pipeline('table-question-answering', model=tapas_model, tokenizer=tapas_tokenizer)


def qa(query,data):
    print(query)
    result = nlp({'table': data,'query':query})
    answer = result['cells']
    print(answer)

prediction = qa("What are the different incident types", table)
```

Facing following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 prediction = qa("What are the different incident types?", table)

Cell In[5], line 12, in qa(query, data)
     10 def qa(query,data):
     11     print(query)
---> 12     result = nlp({'table': data,'query':query})
     13     answer = result['cells']
     14     print(answer)

File c:\Python\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\table_question_answering.py:350, in TableQuestionAnsweringPipeline.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    274 r"""
    275 Answers queries according to a table. The pipeline accepts several types of inputs which are detailed below:
    276 
   (...)
    346     - **aggregator** (`str`) -- If the model has an aggregator, this returns the aggregator.
    347 """
    348 pipeline_inputs = self._args_parser(*args, **kwargs)
--> 350 results = super().__call__(pipeline_inputs, **kwargs)
    351 if len(results) == 1:
    352     return results[0]

File c:\Python\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines\base.py:1100, in Pipeline.__call__(self, inputs, num_workers, batch_size, *args, **kwargs)
...
   2208     # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209     _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210 return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)

IndexError: index out of range in self
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

I can't figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by reducing the size of dateframe (removing rows from the dataframe)